# How to put all the text on a page into a single string

Tags: javascript

So, using just javascript, I want to put all the text on a page into a string. There's probably some really easy way to do it, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an Entire HTML Page to a Single JavaScript String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377564/convert-an-entire-html-page-to-a-single-javascript-string)

Comment: @funnydman - this converts the HTML markup + the text, and not just the text, to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `innerText` of the `body`:

```
document.body.innerText
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <title>Put Text on Me</title>
    <script>
        var sampleText = "Hi I am a text";
        function writeTextOnPage(){
            document.getElementById('putText').innerText = sampleText;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id='putText'></p>
    <input type="button" onclick="writeTextOnPage()" value="Load Here">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Above code is the combination HTML + js. JS code is written inside the script tag inside head tag. as your question is saying put text on the page, so we have created one variable called 'sampleText' and assigning some string value. In the same manner you also put all the string. One function is there which is adding text on button click.