# convert HTML DOM element to JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have a web page with the element:

```
<div id='myid'></div>
```

In chrome dev tools, when I type in the console

```
document.getElementById('myid')
```

returns a html element,

```
<div id='myid'></div>
```

is there an alternative method I can use to view it and it's properties as a JavaScript object instead rather than a html element?

[convert html to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520255/convert-html-to-javascript)

I have seen this post, but all I want to do is get the element, not do any parsing and build something new and ideally in dev tools.

Comment: what does it mean javascript object? `div` equivalent `javascript` object, mean you are mixing `HTML` and `Javascript`.

Comment: no, for example when I use document.getElementById('myid').outerHTML I get a html string returned. I would like to use a method that displays it as a list of elements as an object instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there an alternative method I can use to view it and it's properties as a JavaScript object instead rather than a html element?
>
> all I want to do is get the element, not do any parsing and build something new and ideally in dev tools

Yes **if you are only interested in the dev tools** (console), you can always use **[`console.dir()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)**, it's made for this:

```
console.dir(document.getElementById('myid'));
```

**[`console.dir()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)**:

> Displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child objects.

Answer (score 0):

Would do something like using the Document [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface to access the array of attributes / properties.